# Mapping two graphs in Networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying hard these days to map two different graphs depending on the node they have in common. Here is what the two graphs look like. The colors of the node indicate that *the blue one is **priority1*** and *the yellow one is **priority2***.

[image]

Nodes who share the same node, I want to combine them. Here is what I want to achieve. In this case, 10 and 190 are a common node for 31, 130, 204, and 240 respectively. 
[image]

Here is the code that I tried.

```
for node1, node2 in Graph2.edges():
    if Graph1.has_edge(node1, node2):
        for attr in Graph2.adj[node1][node2]:
            if (Graph1.node[node1]['priority']==1):

                name = str(node1) + '/' + str(node2)            
                mapping = {n1: name, node2: name}
                Graph2 =nx.relabel_nodes(Graph2, mapping)

    pos1 = nx.shell_layout(Graph2) 

    nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(Graph2, pos1, node_size=2000, node_color = 'b' , alpha=0.3, with_labels = True) 
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(Graph2, pos1, width=1.5, alpha=0.3, edge_color='k')
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(Graph2, pos1, font_size=15, font_family='sans-serif')
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this, please?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Do your graphs have a very peculiar structure? The problem that you are trying to solve is called finding a [graph homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism), which is hard for large graphs. Also, in your particular case, the mapping can easily be ambiguous. Imagine your `graph 1` had another node, say `42`, and another two edges, `(10, 42)`, and `(42, 190)`. How would you map `graph 2` to this graph, which now has two triangles instead of one.

Comment: Dear @PaulBrodersen Thank you for your reply. I have a particular structure and I am not focused on the node number. Instead, I am focusing on their priority, as I said above. For example, the blue one is `priority 1` and the yellow one is `priority 2`. What if, node `42` is `priority 2`? Do you think is it ambiguous also to do that?

One more question, is graph homomorphism np-complete?

Comment: Regarding your first question, I just want to raise the issue that there may not be an unambiguous mapping in the first place. Whether or not that is true depends heavily on the shape of your graphs. You "priority" may or may not disambiguate all of these cases, but given a single example that is hard to tell. If I were you, I would look at a bunch of examples, convince myself that there always was a single correct solution, and then maybe expand this question with more examples, or better: an explanation why the mapping is always unambiguous.

Comment: Regarding your seconds question: yes, the general case is NP complete, but there are many special cases that can be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: Thank for your time and explanation, sir!!

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for similar solution, I tried to solve the above problem for priority 1 which means for the nodes with the blue color. The same to do for the rest of the priorities. Here priority and name are my graph attributes.

```
    try:
        for n1, n2, attr in list(graph1.edges(data ='True')):
            for x1, x2, attr1 in list(graph2.edges(data ='True')):
                if ((graph1.node[n1]['priority'] ==1) & (graph1.node[n1]['name'] =='Start')):
                    if ((graph2.node[x1]['priority'] ==1) & (graph2.node[x1]['name'] =='Start')):

                        name1 = str(n1) + '/' + str(x1)
                        mapping1 = {n1: name1, x1:name1}
                        graph1 =nx.relabel_nodes(graph1, mapping1)
                        graph2 =nx.relabel_nodes(graph2, mapping1)


    except KeyError:
        print('')   

    try:
        for n1, n2, attr in list(graph1.edges(data ='True')):
            for x1, x2, attr1 in list(graph2.edges(data ='True')):
                if ((graph1.node[n2]['priority'] ==1) & (graph1.node[n2]['name'] =='End')):
                    if ((graph2.node[x2]['priority'] ==1) & (graph2.node[x2]['name'] =='End')):

                        name1 = str(n2) + '/' + str(x2)
                        mapping1 = {n2: name1, x2:name1}
                        graph1 =nx.relabel_nodes(graph1, mapping1)
                        graph2 =nx.relabel_nodes(graph2, mapping1)


    except KeyError: 
        print('')
```